# Error when importing google cloud for cloud AutoML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl

I have the required libraries installed on my machine:

```
Collecting google-cloud
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/b1/7c54d1950e7808df06642274e677dbcedba57f75307adf2e5ad8d39e5e0e/google_cloud-0.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: google-cloud
Successfully installed google-cloud-0.34.0
```

However when I actually try to setup my dataset on cloud storage as per the instructions tutorial I am getting an error stating that the package is not installed, when clearly it is :

```
File "automl_vision_dataset.py", line 280, in <module>
project_id, compute_region, args.dataset_name, multilabel
File "automl_vision_dataset.py", line 37, in create_dataset
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl
ImportError: No module named google.cloud
```

Can you please help? what am I missing here? thanks

Comment: Hi @Bira, thanks, I already solved the problem back then if I recall properly - it was a few months ago. I was already using virtualenv and pip as package manager and the module was properly installed, issue was to do with how the import was specificied if I recall properly

Comment: what edit do you refer to? that was a few months ago so I do not even remember. What I can say is that this was not a question about the virtues or need of using virtualenv (the topic of your answer), but rather an import of a library that was failing, which I then corrected via the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `pip install google-cloud-automl`

Comment: I don't know why installing `google-cloud` doesn't give you `google.cloud`. You'd have to ask Google why they did that. Here's a relevant page: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-automl/